# Move the ytick vertically in plot python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a histogram plot and I want to move the yticks vertically (0.2 cm lower than their positions of the existing yticks).
I searched a lot and I could not find anything which exactly did this. Could you please help me with that? I attached an image here that shows the new location of the y ticks. [image]

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

VAL = [8, 4, 5, 20]
objects = ['h', 'b', 'c', 'a']
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))

cmap = plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn_r')
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=min(VAL), vmax=max(VAL))
ax = sns.barplot(x=VAL, y=objects, hue=VAL, palette='RdYlGn_r', dodge=False)

plt.yticks(y_pos, objects)

plt.show()
```

Comment: As seaborn reverses the y-axis for horizontal bar plots, you can use `ax.set_yticks(y_pos+0.2, objects)` instead of `plt.yticks(y_pos, objects)`.  Note that here the distance is measured in data units, and the distance between two bars is one unit.

Comment: If you only want to change the tick marks but keep the tick labels at their original position, you can work with major ticks for one and minor ticks for the other.

Comment: The other solution also works for me. So I will accept a solution to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we want the offset to scale with plot size, it's best to base the offset on the step-size of y_pos. We store that as `dy` and then add a fraction of it as an offset in `yticks()`.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

VAL = [8, 4, 5, 20]
objects = ['h', 'b', 'c', 'a']
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
dy = y_pos[1] - y_pos[0]

cmap = plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn_r')
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=min(VAL), vmax=max(VAL))
ax = sns.barplot(x=VAL, y=objects, hue=VAL, palette='RdYlGn_r', dodge=False)

plt.yticks(y_pos + 0.1*dy, objects)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the trick is:

```
yticks = ax.yaxis.get_ticklocs()
new_yticks = yticks + 0.2
ax.set_yticks(new_yticks)
```

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

VAL = [8, 4, 5, 20]
objects = ['h', 'b', 'c', 'a']

cmap = plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn_r')
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=min(VAL), vmax=max(VAL))
ax = sns.barplot(x=VAL, y=objects, hue=VAL, palette='RdYlGn_r', dodge=False)

yticks = ax.yaxis.get_ticklocs()
new_yticks = yticks + 0.2
ax.set_yticks(new_yticks)

plt.show()
```

[image]